# Android: How to add event handler by android:onClick in custom_layout.xml for button in custom dialog?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, dialog

I'm newbie for android development. I'm trying to set event handler for a button that is in custom dialog by using android:onClick in layout.xml. But when I debug application, it said that it cannot find a source code when button in custom dialog is clicked. But it works well when I use event listener instead of attribute in layout file.

Here is some of code

Main activity which contains button1 and below is event handler for that button

```
public void onClickButton1(View v)
    {
        MyCustomDialog a = new MyCustomDialog(this);        
        a.show();       
    }
```

and here is MyCustomDialog class, another java file

```
public class MyCustomDialog extends Dialog {

    Context m_context;
    public MyCustomDialog (Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.m_context = context;       
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setTitle("Custom Dialog");
        this.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
    }



    public void onClickButtonInDialog(View v)
    {
        AlertDialog a = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.m_context).create();
        a.setTitle("Ok");
        a.show();
    }
}
```

And the last one is custom dialog layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_in_dialog"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:onClick="onClickButtonInDialog"
        android:text="Add" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Could you post the logcat output of when you use the code as is above?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible. You'll have to register a callback like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setTitle("Custom Dialog");
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog);
    this.setContentView(v);
    v.findViewById(R.id.button_in_dialog).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onClickButtonInDialog(v);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: "It's not possible." -> I'm not sure that's entirely true. Check out this link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:onClick

Comment: He'd have to implement this callback in the context that were passed to the dialog, since the system calls this callback via reflection using the context assigned to the dialog. It seems that this is not what Golff is planning, and besides that, it's not a good idea because the activity and the dialog won't be loosely coupled as they should.

Comment: Bingo. I guess it's just a question of.. "malpractice" now. :D

Answer (score 0):

As you can [see here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3aonClick), it IS possible to do that. But you're gonna have to put your onClick handler in the context of the same activity you set the view in. They haven't really mentioned in detail (or at all) if it's possible for the onClick from a Dialog's context to be used. Put the listener in your activity, and just create the dialog as you already are. That way it'll register the listener, and you'll still have your custom dialog.